# Remove DLL from solution and create a new project to implement that dll functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have a project, and it uses 4 DLL's from Nuget Package(Coming from another team within our project). Now, our project no longer wants to use these DLL's.
I just wanted to understand, if its possible to remove those DLL's and write a new project all together, with same functionality of those DLL's? or any other way possible.

Please sugest

Comment: The details are kind of sketchy here but in general - yes, it's entirely possible to remove a nuget package and replace it with another - be it another project in the same solution, or a different dll...

Comment: Thank You. i just wanted to understand in General, If I can remove a DLL from solution, and write a new code to replace that DLL.